# GeckoFX 60 Pages load too slow on heavy navigating

Tags: vb.net, html-agility-pack, geckofx

i have a vb.net multi-threading app which navigating to about 1000 page or more everyday at the same time using GeckoFx 60

then using Html Agility Pack to parse page contents

my problem is when navigating to many pages at the same time , some of this pages load too slow ( about 20 minutes ) and also it's taking more than 10 GB of Ram

i tried to replace geckofx with cefsharp but i couldn't get it to work

is there any solution for this please ??

Comment: Don't let 1000 Geckos loose at the same time would be a start. You need to throttle the parsing procedure/objects creation and destruction. Look for *throttle* / *throttling* and *Task*.

Comment: @Jimi
but unfortunately i need all geckos to navigate at the same time